# Camera2, Images get saved to gallery as blank images with exclamation mark

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-camera2

Don't know why it's doing this, here's my code, maybe I did something wrong and don't realize it?

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

      mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage()));

    }
};

private class ImageSaver implements Runnable{

    private final Image mImage;

    public ImageSaver(Image image){
        mImage = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){  

       ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

       byte[] bytes= new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()]; 

       byteBuffer.get(bytes);  

       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

        try{
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFileName); 
            fileOutputStream.write(bytes); 
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{  //finally cleans up the resources created in this runnable
            mImage.close();

            if (fileOutputStream !=null){
                try{
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void createImageFolder() {   
    File imageFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    mImageFolder = new File(imageFile, "camera2VideoImage");   
    if (!mImageFolder.exists()) {   
        mImageFolder.mkdirs();
    } 
}


private File createImageFileName() throws IOException {  
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String prepend = "IMAGE_" + timestamp + "_";
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".jpg", mImageFolder);
    mImageFileName = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();  
    return imageFile;
}
```

This code should work, I receive no error in Log-cat. I take my pictures but when I look at what's saved in gallery, the picture appears as a grey screen with a white encircled exclamation mark. What have I done wrong or not included?

Comment: Does this all happen on emulator?

Comment: On my Galaxy note 8 device.

Comment: Does the default camera app work? Also, install some third party app.

Comment: Please add the code where you create the ImageReader and connect it to the camera.